# TypeError using Watson Assistant V2 in Node-RED

Tags: websphere, ibm-watson, node-red, watson-assistant

I'm trying to set up Watson Assistant for a Telegram Bot I'm building. Right know I have no problem getting answers from Watson using **watson-assistant-v1** (i.e. assistant node), however, I'd like to use **watson-assistant-v2** (i.e. assistant V2 node).

I do not know what I am doing wrong. For the API Key in Node-RED I'm using the API Key of the Assitant. However, when I send a message to the bot in debug I get "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Am I missing something else? Why is this error happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Assistant V1 node, the configuration is the Workspace ID.

In the Assistant V2 node, the configuration is for the Assistant ID.

For both input text is expected in `msg.payload`, though this can be empty to allow a dialog to be initiated. So for the V2 node this is a valid flow that should work

```
[{"id":"83dbc697.d416c8","type":"inject","z":"f551e981.a6bf78","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":90,"y":260,"wires":[["d334bd1c.00abb"]]},{"id":"d334bd1c.00abb","type":"watson-assistant-v2","z":"f551e981.a6bf78","name":"","service-endpoint":"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api","assistant_id":"f6f33980-9b6a-4bdf-92dd-e7974a832586","debug":false,"restart":false,"return_context":true,"alternate_intents":false,"multisession":true,"timeout":"","optout-learning":false,"x":410,"y":260,"wires":[["151a548c.d4f44b","6ad0ad7b.b34414"]]},{"id":"151a548c.d4f44b","type":"debug","z":"f551e981.a6bf78","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","x":650,"y":240,"wires":[]}]
```

If you are setting up a dialog then you need to set up a context. Both nodes can manage the context for you, but they need an identifier for the context. For the V2 node this done by setting `msg.params.session_id` to an arbitrary value that makes sense to your application. eg.

```
[{"id":"b30a8bd4.e5f628","type":"inject","z":"f551e981.a6bf78","name":"","topic":"","payload":"Hello","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":90,"y":300,"wires":[["4c5c73b5.eef91c"]]},{"id":"4c5c73b5.eef91c","type":"function","z":"f551e981.a6bf78","name":"","func":"msg.params = {\n    \"session_id\" : \"ABC\"\n};\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":310,"y":360,"wires":[["d334bd1c.00abb"]]},{"id":"d334bd1c.00abb","type":"watson-assistant-v2","z":"f551e981.a6bf78","name":"","service-endpoint":"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api","assistant_id":"f6f33980-9b6a-4bdf-92dd-e7974a832586","debug":false,"restart":false,"return_context":true,"alternate_intents":false,"multisession":true,"timeout":"","optout-learning":false,"x":410,"y":260,"wires":[["151a548c.d4f44b","6ad0ad7b.b34414"]]},{"id":"151a548c.d4f44b","type":"debug","z":"f551e981.a6bf78","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","x":650,"y":240,"wires":[]}]
```

The node then manages the session and context for you, renewing the session whenever it expires.